# How to send a .JSON file through API (POST) on EG?

Tags: sas

I've trying to send a JSON file through SAS Enterprise Guide, But I believe that I'm doing some mistake on code.

Below is there my code:

**>> GENERATE JSON FILE:**

```
   data teste30;
    set MATABLES.TEMPJSON;
     RESP=cat(CUSTOMERID,"|",RESPTRACKING_CD);
     CODSMS="WXS";  
     MOBILE="5511111111";
     DATAPARA="09/05/2019";
     DATALIMI="10/05/2019";
     REMETENTE="TF";
    run;    


filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set teste30;
  file code ;
  put 'WRITE OPEN OBJECT;'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "TP_SMS" ' CODSMS :$quote. ';' 
    / 'WRITE VALUES "NM_REMETENTESMS" ' REMETENTE :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "NR_TELEFONECELULARSMS" ' MOBILE :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "TX_MENSAGEMSMS" ' msgtext :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "DT_PARAENVIOSMS" ' DATAPARA  :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "DT_LIMITEENVIOSMS" ' DATALIMI  :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE VALUES "DS_CHAVEORIGEMSMS" ' RESP :$quote. ';'
    / 'WRITE CLOSE;'
  ;
run;

proc json out="%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))/TEST.json" pretty nokeys nosastags;
  write open array; /* container for all the data */
  %include code;
  write close;    /* container for all the data */
run;
```

My JSON seems ok.  The problem occours when I try to send it calling the  API:

**>> CALLING API POST**

```
FILENAME POSTA "C:\TEMP\POSTA.TXT";
FILENAME code2 "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))/test.json";
PROC HTTP
    URL="HTTPS://*********/SMS/INCLUISMS"
    CT="APPLICATION/JSON"
    IN=code2
    METHOD="POST"
    OUT=POSTA;
    HEADERS
        "HOST"="*****"
        "AUTHORIZATION"="BEARER xxxxxxxxxxxx"  
        "CONTENT-TYPE"="APPLICATION/JSON"
        "CONTENT-LENGTH"="xx"

RUN;
%echoFile(fn=code2);


%PUT HTTP STATUS CODE = &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE. : &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_PHRASE.;
```

The log on EG return this error:
ERROR: The tcpSockRead call failed. The system error is 'The connection was reset by a peer.'.
ERROR: Connection has been closed.

I tried input the path & filename (physical) on "IN=" (example: IN="C:\TEMP\Test.json) - without success.

Has anyone had a similar experience like this? How can I send the JSON (file) using "IN=" ?   Is it possible?

Tks Guys!

Comment: This is what returns but I don't think it's your issue: http://support.sas.com/kb/12/210.html I suspect instead you're having this issue: http://support.sas.com/kb/57/595.html

Comment: Another thing to try: there is a bug involving HTTPS in a later version of SAS when they switched `proc http` from Java to C. Try adding the undocumented option `java_http` to see if it resolves the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Reeza. I believe this error is on my code because I succeed when I did a POST using only one variable in the body.

Comment: Show the code that works vs the code that doesn't work then.

Answer (score 0):

When I haver using the "datafiles" with only one parameter, it is working normaly.  I've success on API call.  Below is there the code:

```js
/* Put the body of the JSON content in external file */
filename json_in temp;
data _null_;
file json_in;
input;
put _infile_;
datalines;
{ "Tp_Email":"CCA001" }
run;

filename posta "c:\temp\posta.txt";
filename post1 temp;
proc http
 url="https://***********/*****/***/ObterEmailTexto"
 method="POST"
 ct="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 in=json_in
    out=posta;
 headers
  "Host"="****"
  "Authorization"="bearer &TOKEN"  
  "Content-Type"="application/json"
  "Content-Length"="**"
  "CD_Login"="*****";
Run;
/*
data _null_;
   infile posta;
   input;
   put _infile_;
run;
*/
%put HTTP Status code = &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE. : &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_PHRASE.;
```

When I tried pass the JSON file on body, occurred the error informed.

```js
FILENAME POSTA "C:\TEMP\POSTA.TXT";
FILENAME code2 "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))/test.json";
PROC HTTP java_http
 URL="HTTPS://**********/*****/SMS/INCLUISMS"
    ct="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 IN=code2
 METHOD="POST"
    OUT=POSTA;
 HEADERS
  "HOST"="*****"
  "AUTHORIZATION"="BEARER &TOKEN"  
  "CONTENT-TYPE"="APPLICATION/JSON"
  "CONTENT-LENGTH"="**"
  "CD_LOGIN"="******";
RUN;
 

%PUT HTTP STATUS CODE = &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE. : &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_PHRASE.;
```

Witout **java_http** options:  ERROR: The tcpSockRead call failed. The system error is 'The connection was reset by a peer.'.  ERROR: Connection has been closed.

With **java_http** options: ERROR: Statement HEADERS is not supported in Java execution mode.

Tks. again!!!
TF